# Python PyQt5: How to get the name and the content of an image file by QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5, qimage, qfiledialog

How to open an image file with QFileDialog?
I also want to know how to get the name of the file e.g. the image file is named "photo.png" and I want to print its name.

```
def openImage(self):
    fileName = QFileDialog(self)
    fileName.getOpenFileName()
    image = QImage(fileName)
    print(fileName.FileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem on my own:

```
def openImage(self):
    fileName = QFileDialog().getOpenFileName()
    filePath = str(fileName[0])

    image = QImage(filePath)

    label = QLabel()
    label.setPixmap(QPixmap().fromImage(image))

    self.addWidget(label, 0, 0)

    fileObject = filePath.split('/')
    file = fileObject[ len(fileObject) - 1 ]
    print(file)
```

Comment: A pixmap can load an image directly from a file-path, so all you need is: `label.setPixmap(QPixmap(filePath))`.